# success in lowdb add/edit/update/delete but need some changes in update parts by using if/then/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json

I have completed the add/delete/edit/update codes using express and lowdb database, but it's quite basic especially in update parts whereas, i would like to use if/then/else statement but with my little brain could not do it alone;  codes here below:

```js
/* Update the data from displayed table of editup.pug */
router.post('/update', (req, res, next) =>  {
  db.read(); //read current datas in db
  let uid = req.body.id; // transfer "id" from TABLE to "uid"
/* Do actual updation of User via ID */
  db.get('users')
  .find({id: uid})
  .assign({First_Name: req.body.First_Name})
  .assign({Middle_Name: req.body.Middle_Name})
  .assign({Last_Name: req.body.Last_Name})
  .assign({Email: req.body.Email})
  .write();
/* Do actual updation of User via ID ends here */
 res.status(200);
res.redirect('/');
});
```

Here below the complete codes:

**app.js**

```js
var port = 3000
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var shortid = require('shortid');

var low = require('lowdb');
var FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
var adapter = new FileSync('./DBase/shortIdDB.json');
var db = low(adapter);

// default user list
 db.defaults({ users: [] }).write();

/* GET data listing. Display list of current data in table */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>  {
 db.read(); //read current datas in db
 var putusers=db.get('users'); // use 'users:' section of db
 var data = putusers.value(); // transfer values from getusers to data
 res.render('index', { data }); // Send values from data to Table
console.log('Your Datas:', data);
});

// Form post -- Start adding data from FORM to DB
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
 db.read(); //read current datas in db
 /* start collecting data from FORM */
 var FormFeed = {
 id:  shortid.generate(),
 First_Name: req.body.FName, 
 Middle_Name: req.body.MName, 
 Last_Name: req.body.LName, 
 Email: req.body.EMail}; 
/* collect data from FORM end here */ 
 db.get('users').push(FormFeed).write(); // push and write to the db
res.redirect('/');
});

// delete selected record via id
router.get('/delete', function(req, res) {
 db.read(); //read current datas in db
 let uid = req.query.id;  // transfer "id" from TABLE to "uid"
 let data = db.get('users').find({ id: uid }).value(); // find and collect data via "uid"
 console.log("User to Process: ", data, "and the id: ", uid);
 /* Do actual deletion of User via ID */
 db.get('users')
 .remove({ id: uid })
 .write();
 /* Do actual deletion of User via ID End here!!! */
 res.status(200);
res.redirect('/');
 });

/* GET data via ID to update and display data in table */
router.get('/toupdate', (req, res, next) =>  {
  db.read(); //read current datas in db
  let uid = req.query.id; // transfer "id" from TABLE to "uid"
  let dataup = db.get('users').find({ id: uid }).value(); // find and collect data via "uid"
  console.log("User to Process: ", dataup, "and the id: ", uid);
res.render('editup', { dataup }); // Send values from data to Table
});

/* Update the data from displayed table of editup.pug */
router.post('/update', (req, res, next) =>  {
  db.read(); //read current datas in db
  let uid = req.body.id; // transfer "id" from TABLE to "uid"
/* Do actual updation of User via ID */
  db.get('users')
  .find({id: uid})
  .assign({First_Name: req.body.First_Name})
  .assign({Middle_Name: req.body.Middle_Name})
  .assign({Last_Name: req.body.Last_Name})
  .assign({Email: req.body.Email})
  .write();
/* Do actual updation of User via ID ends here */
 res.status(200);
res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.pug**

```html
extends layout
block content
  .container
    h2 NodeJs Express LowDB - View Add, Edit/Update, Delete records
    .success
    .error
    form(id='form1' method='post')
      input#id(type='hidden', name='id', value='')
      table
        tr
          td(style='text-align: center')
            input#First_Name(type='text',name='FName', placeholder='First Name', value='')
            | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            input#Middle_Name(type='text',name='MName', placeholder='Middle Name', value='')
            | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            input#Last_Name(type='text',name='LName', placeholder='Last Name', value='')
            | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            input#Email(type='text',name='EMail', placeholder='Email Address', value='')
            | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            input#subbtn(type="submit" onclick="javascript: form.action='/Add'" Value='Add')

      tbody
      table
          tr
            th id
            th First Name
            th Middle Name
            th Last Name
            th Email
            th(colspan='2') Action 
          each users in data
            tr
              td= users.id 
              td= users.First_Name
              td= users.Middle_Name
              td= users.Last_Name
              td= users.Email
              td(id="tdclck1"): a(href='http://localhost:3000/toupdate?id='+users.id) Edit  
              td(id="tdclck2"): a(href='http://localhost:3000/delete?id='+users.id) Delete
```

**editup.pug**

```html
extends layout
block content
  .container
    h2 NodeJs Express LowDB - View Add, Edit/Update, Delete records
    .success
    .error
    form(id='form2' method='post')
      table
          tr
            th id
            th First Name
            th Middle Name
            th Last Name
            th Email
            th Action
          tr()
            td()
             input(type='text',name='id',readonly,value=dataup.id)
            td()
             input(type='text',name='First_Name',value=dataup.First_Name)
            td()
             input(type='text',name='Middle_Name',value=dataup.Middle_Name)
            td()
             input(type='text',name='Last_Name',value=dataup.Last_Name)
            td()
             input(type='text',name='Email',value=dataup.Email)
            td
             input#subbtn(type="submit" onclick="javascript: form.action='/Update'" Value='Update')
    a(href="/") << back
```

**shotidDB.json**

```js
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "-34BAqsS",
      "First_Name": "Kauna-unahan",
      "Middle_Name": "Kagitna-ginaan",
      "Last_Name": "Kahuli-hulihan",
      "Email": "sdfg@sdfv.dfc"
    },
    {
      "id": "wtWsbepJ",
      "First_Name": "Pangalan",
      "Middle_Name": "GitnangPangalan",
      "Last_Name": "HulingPangalan",
      "Email": "kljjl123@ooo.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "zyBMsLtJ",
      "First_Name": "Kalatsa",
      "Middle_Name": "palitsako",
      "Last_Name": "ayooo",
      "Email": "walay.ayo@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "vxqDSrPm",
      "First_Name": "newuser",
      "Middle_Name": "newmid",
      "Last_Name": "newlast",
      "Email": "newmail@mail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "ybl4yvNS",
      "First_Name": "Kaunaunahan Ngalan",
      "Middle_Name": "Kagitnagitnaan Pangalan",
      "Last_Name": "Apelyido",
      "Email": "kakaape@email.ph"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have managed to change the update part implementing the if/else statement, the code is herebelow:

```js
/* Update the data from displayed table of editup.pug Revision 1 */
router.post('/update', (req, res, next) =>  {
 
 db.read(); //read current datas in db
 let uid = req.body.id; // transfer "id" from TABLE to "uid"
 /* Do actual updation of User via ID */
 let dataup = db.get('users').find({ id: uid }).value();
  if (dataup.First_Name === req.body.First_Name) {
   console.log("No change in First_Name");
   } else {
    db.get('users').find({id: uid})
    .assign({First_Name: req.body.First_Name})
    .write();
    }
  if (dataup.Middle_Name === req.body.Middle_Name) {
   console.log("No change in Middle_Name");
   } else {
    db.get('users').find({id: uid})
    .assign({Middle_Name: req.body.Middle_Name})
    .write();
    }
  if (dataup.Last_Name === req.body.Last_Name) {
   console.log("No change in Last_Name");
   } else {
    db.get('users').find({id: uid})
    .assign({Last_Name: req.body.Last_Name})
    .write();
    }
  if (dataup.Email === req.body.Email) {
   console.log("No change in Email");
   } else {
    db.get('users').find({id: uid})
    .assign({Email: req.body.Email})
    .write();
    }
 /* Do actual updation of User via ID ends here */
res.status(200);
res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so my advise would be to add a function that does this for you since there is a lot of repetition.

```
if (dataup.Last_Name === req.body.Last_Name) {
    console.log("No change in Last_Name");
} else {
    db.get('users').find({id: uid})
        .assign({Last_Name: req.body.Last_Name})
        .write();
}
```

Like so:

```
function updateUser(userParam, userId, dbIntance, dataup){

    if (dataup.userParam=== req.body.userParam) {
        console.log(`No change in ${userParam}`);
    } else {
        dbIntance.get('users').find({id: userId})
            .assign({userParam: req.body.userParam})
            .write();
    }
}
```

So Now just replace all the ifs with this piece of code.

```
const userDetail = ['First_Name ', 'Middle_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email']

for(let i=0; i<userDetail.length; i++){
    this.updateUser(userDetail[i], uid, db, dataup);
}
```

Clean and consice thats the goal and also bit more than basic. You can checkout this link below to see controller based structuing for Nodejs a bit advance stuff to get you going.
Hope it helps :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes